# Why does everyone in Fionavar understand English?

Tags: guy-gavriel-kay, the-summer-tree, the-fionavar-tapestry

In the first [Fionavar Tapestry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fionavar_Tapestry) novel ['The Summer Tree'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Summer_Tree), 5 [University of Toronto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Toronto) students are transported via wizard to the ur-dimension/world of Fionavar from which all of other universes and worlds are a partial reflection of.  And out of universe because most novels don't like giving the readers too many obvious unsolicited linguistic lessons the Fionavarians can understand the Canadians and they can more or less understand everyone else.  Though there is, at least, one or two other languages (mostly elves).

[image: The Fionavar Tapestry omnibus cover]

Because I listened to the audiobook version and I was a little distracted, I probably missed where the author explains why everyone understands each other.

Is it the classic magic spell or maybe they literally speak english and we just copied them or something else?

Comment: This is a super common [trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslatorMicrobes) of most "dropped in a fantasy world" works, to the point that it's notable when it's averted or explicitly called out.

Comment: @DavidW - Yeah, no doubt, but the author is pretty detailed and painstaking in his world building.  I'd be slightly surprised if he didn't drop a line somewhere in the text about it.

Comment: This is a universe where cross-dimensional travel to Earth (where a huge chunk of people speak English) has been happening for hundreds of years. Maybe English just took over as the dominant world language.

Comment: Since Fionavar is the primary world, presumably English originated there.

Comment: Yeah, I figure its either it originated in Fionavar or the wizard hand waved a spell.  I just want to know which one the author picked if anything or something else.  (Though, as an aside, why not Latin, Persian, etc or some advanced future language)